# Pass a variable to sass from programming language (coldfusion or PHP)

Tags: haml, sass

I would like to pass a variable to my sass from coldfusion or php.

Above  I declare a var  that I need to pass to sass to set a container-size in my _base.sass.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What's the use case for this? User visits your site, you capture their browser window size, pass it to Sass, compile the CSS given this value, and then render the page? Sounds highly inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

Use the !default flag in your variable to do this.  here's what i mean

```
// SCSS file
@import "php-variables"; // have php write this file first before compiling
@import "variables"; // custom colors, font-sizes, etc.

// contents of php-variables

$myvar: #f00; // the value you're setting with php

// contents of variables

$myvar: #0f0 !default; // the value to use if php DOESN't override it.
```

This way you can still have a fallback for if your php code doesn't need to override a var.  anything you write in the php file will be declared first.  then as long as your variables file uses the !default flag on ALL variables then it won't override the php set ones.

more info here:

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_

I have tested this with the php compiler at http://www.phpsass.com/ and it works.

Comment: I know it has been a few years since you answered this question but I am facing the same issue and I think your solution would work, my only issue is that my colour needs to change like maybe fetch it from my database depending on the domain. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be writing directly to the sass file through php/coldfusion. I doubt there is another way to do it.

An easy way to do this would just be to put your variable on your first line in the sass file or something and just overwrite the value using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution i found was to do the following. In your html file (mine is a Blade template) you can inject your variable ($bodyBgColour):

```
<style>
    :root {
        --main-bg-color: {{ $bodyBgColour }}
</style>
```

Then in your scss file you can use it:

```
$background-colour: var(--main-bg-color);
```

And you can subsequently use that sass variable in your classes:

```
body {
    background-color: $background-colour;
}
```