# Defining CSS colour through php

Tags: php, css, sass, less, stylesheet

I need a way of defining a css highlight colour as a php value and then using that as a class in my stylesheets.

I know that someone people do this as inline styles but I just have far too many elements using the class to put it inline. Ideally I need a way to echo the variable in the stylesheet (SASS?)

I can't find this anywhere, which seems odd!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17302207/2887133

Comment: Dynamically inserting inline style or class is your best option.

Comment: Don't insert it into your stylesheet.  Instead, In your output (ideally in the `<head>` section of your page), at some point after your stylesheet is referenced, cause PHP to do something like this: `echo '<style>.highlight_color {color: #ffff00;}</style>`.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have 2 viable options.

### Using Javascript

The first option is using some javascript inside your HTML file, in a `script` tag.

Define a variable with PHP and use it to target the desired elements.

```js
var myVariable = "dodgerblue";

$(".el").css("background-color", myVariable);
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: example;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  counter-increment: example;
}
div::after {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  content: counter(example);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el"></div>
<div class="el"></div>
<div class="el"></div>
<div class="el"></div>
<div class="el"></div>
```

---

Another option is like **@cale_b** suggests.

### Using an internal stylesheet.

> In your output (ideally in the  section of your page), at some
>   point after your stylesheet is referenced, cause PHP to do something
>   like this: `echo <style>.highlight_color {color: #ffff00;}</style>`.

---

### Using CSS is not possible at the moment.

Sadly there is not a CSS solution for this, yet.

Hopefully some day browsers will support the use of `attr()` CSS function in all property values, not just content.

```css
div {
  background-color: attr(data-myvariable);
}
div::after {
  content: attr(data-myvariable);
}
```

```html
<div data-myvariable="red">
  Example
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! So it looks like I have to add the variable to every instance, which is a shame. I'll get to work!

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no other alternative that comes to mind. If you found this helpful you can mark it as the correct answer.