# How to use variables from backend in .scss files

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a site built with Django, Python and Wagtail.

What I want is to be able to add some styles in the backend and then use it in my frontent's `.scss` files.

For example I want to be able to set a `primary color` to `#fff` via backend and then use it in my `.scss` file as:

```
$g-color-primary: primary_color_from_backend;
$g-font-size-default: primary_font_size_from_backend;
```

I do not have any idea how I can do that and if it's possible at all?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In short, it is not possible. Look on answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300909/sending-dynamic-variables-to-sass#answer-17302207).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible. You can instead define different classes in the CSS file, then use them in your HTML template dependent on the  Django template variables there.

Answer (score 0):

This would require to write out the sass color variables content (with scss syntax) in a physical .scss file, which depends on your development environment. And then import it into other .scss file to get compiled and output through a frontend build process tool like Gulp, Webpack.

For example, Webpack's sass-loader plugin provides option to prepend sass code at Frontend build/compile time.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            prependData: '$env: ' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ';',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```